# mysql snytax error in foreach loop

Tags: mysql

I run the page and this error comes up. I still cannot find out where is the problem:

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'right,createtime) VALUES ('test10', 1, 1, now())' at line 2

```
foreach($array as $value){

    //insert record
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO projectright
        (generalusername,projectid,right,createtime)
        VALUES
        ('$_POST[username]',
        ".$value.",
        1,
        now())";    

        if (!mysql_query($sql2,$con))

  {

  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`right` is reserved keyword

you should escape it by backticks like that

```
   INSERT INTO projectright
    (generalusername,projectid,`right`,createtime)
    .....
    .....
```

take a look to [reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-7.html) when creating/playing by columns , and escape them by backticks.

try this:

```
  foreach($array as $value){


 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO projectright
    (generalusername,projectid,`right`,createtime)
    VALUES
    (".$_POST['username'].",
    ".$value.",
    1,
    now())";    

    if (!mysql_query($sql2,$con))

  {

  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }
 }
```

- as strawberry said: Better to not take reserved keywords.

Comment: A better idea is to not use reserved words

Comment: You welcome @Annie :) , consider to accept answer as solved :).

Answer (score 0):

$value is an array and this is the cause of the error most probably. Try something like:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO projectright
        (generalusername,projectid,right,createtime)
        VALUES
        ('$_POST[username]',
        ".implode($value).",
        1,
        now())";
```